# How to create iReport with two different data source of Main and Subreport

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport, subreport

I need to create a report combining data from SQL server and from PostgreSQL. I was already looking for tutorials online but got no help.

I already have created before reports with multiple subreports but using only one data source. But never done multiple data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Map of parameters and put sql in map, then send parameters to report.
sql could be created from any data base

```
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("SQL_INPUT", sql);
JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, connection);
```

in report 
you create parameter with name SQL_INPUT
and replace query with $P!{SQL_INPUT}